# Return type safety for overloaded functions, TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-safety

The code below would fail. The TypeScript would (wrongly) think that the return type is `string` and would allow you to call `charAt` method on it, when it's actually a `number`.

Is there a way to improve the code so that TypeScript will detect the bug?

```
function fn(s: number): number
function fn(n: string): string
function fn(arg: any): any { return 0 }

fn("hi").charAt(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tell Typescript something is true, then it will assume you are telling the truth.

Simply remove `function fn(n: string): string` to detect that bug. Only define what is actually true.

Ignoring the test case, the base case for method overloading is not defined correctly.
Referring to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads
the base case should be declared as `function fn(arg):any`. Notice the lack of a type on the parameter.

This still would not see the given code as a bug since the `fn(n:string):string` overload is deduced from the given parameter.